# CSS Selectors not following text - weird behavior

Tags: html, css

I have this css selector which is working weirdly. It's to create a circle highlight around a text. But When the text goes to the next line, the circle doesn't follow it. What I mean is given in the image below,

[image: Selector]

Like you see, the word 'Mongoose' doesn't have the selector and the selector is on the line above. This is my SCSS code,

```html
<div>
  front-end framework, <strong>Bootstrap</strong>, which is a front-end styling framework, 
  HTML and CSS. Vue.js can be used to make <strong>AJAX</strong> requests, make flexible 
  and stable websites. Vue.js makes axios requests to the server that is built upon Node.js. 
  <strong>ExpressJS</strong> is a library for Noe that includes a tonne of functions to 
  handle requests and send reponses back to front-ends. The database being used is MongoDB. 
  <strong>Mongoose</strong> is a javascript library that bridges the gap between mongo 
  shell commands and javascript. Furthermore, the web
</div>
```

```scss
strong {
  position:relative;
  color: $color-grey-1 !important;
}

strong:before {
  content:"";
  z-index:-1;
  top:-0.1em;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style:solid;
  border-color: $color-yellow;
  position:absolute;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  width:100%;
  height:1em;
  transform:rotate(2deg);
  border-radius:50%;
  padding:0.1em 0.25em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

This happens every time the word on the edge breaks to the next line. Can someone tell me what I can do to prevent that, and let the selector always be with the text?

Comment: Can you post the bit of relevant HTML.

Comment: @AHaworth Not sure if that is relevant here, but I've updated the question to include the HTML!

Comment: @hrishikeshpaul I know it is not your exact demand but rotate is necessary? If you prefer to not to use rotating border you can use for the element directly  border: solid 4px #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-right-color:transparent;
  padding:1px;

Comment: @oguzhancerit yeah I was doing that previously. But this is to give like a more "natural" feel to it. I wonder why this doesn't work . Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was not using the display inline block inside strong. You can try now

```css
strong {
    position:relative;
    color: grey !important;
  display: inline-block;
  
  }
  
  strong::before {
    
    content:"";
    z-index:-1;
    top:-0.1em;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color: yellow;
    position:absolute;
    border-right-color:transparent;
    width:100%;
    height: 1em;
    transform:rotate(2deg);
    border-radius:50%;
    padding:0.1em 0.25em;
   
  }
```

```html
<div>
  front-end framework, <strong>Bootstrap</strong>, which is a front-end styling framework, 
  HTML and CSS. Vue.js can be used to make <strong>AJAX</strong> requests, make flexible 
  and stable websites. Vue.js makes axios requests to the server that is built upon Node.js. 
  <strong>ExpressJS</strong> is a library for Noe that includes a tonne of functions to 
  handle requests and send reponses back to front-ends. The database being used is MongoDB. 
  <strong>Mongoose</strong> is a javascript library that bridges the gap between mongo 
  shell commands and javascript. Furthermore, the web
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The logo/::before isnt directly connected to to the main element (containig the word mongoose). you could maybe attempt to force them on the same line with `width: max-content;`

so try adding

`strong { width: max-content; }`

Comment: i tried it with normal text which was then forced on one line, so i assumed it worked

Comment: I tried your answer on codepen and it is not working